# How use throttling in Wso2 EI using client IP

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am planning to use throttling in  wso2-ei 6.4.0, From local system i tested the scenario i face some problems could please help me if any one know thanks in advance.

If we restart the wso2-ei node policy is not working.  It taking again from starting ( suppose request limit is 10 for 1 hour,Before restarting the node it processing  5 request after restarting it should take remaining 5 request but it accepting 10 request

Throttling  is working based on wso2-ei node level but suppose Linux server having 10 nodes how to distribute the throttling policy in Linux server level .

How to consider client ip in throttling. If request coming from F5 load balance i need to consider the requested system IP not F5 server IP.

Answer (score 1):

> If we restart the wso2-ei node policy is not working. It taking again from starting ( suppose request limit is 10 for 1 hour,Before restarting the node it processing 5 request after restarting it should take remaining 5 request but it accepting 10 request

The throttle mediator does not store the throttle count. Therefore if you perform a server restart it will reset the throttle count value and start from zero. In a production environment, it is not expected to have frequent server restarts.

> Throttling is working based on wso2-ei node level but suppose Linux server having 10 nodes how to distribute the throttling policy in Linux server level .

If you want to maintain the throttle count across all the nodes you need to cluster the nodes. Throttle mediator uses hazelcast cluster messages to maintain a global count across the cluster.

Comment: Many  Thanks for your answer .

Comment: Could you please provide any link/document  for how to clustering for wso2 EI nodes in Linux server. thanks in advance

Comment: you can follow the steps in the documentation 

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile